# Easiest way to copy ssh key (Used for GIT) from one linux machine to another

Tags: linux, git, ssh-keys

I have a ssh key in a dev environment for GIT access . Now I am changing my dev environment. So Is it safe to copy the ssh key or I should generate one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is for ssh private keys to never ever leave the machine on which they are generated. So the usual approach is to generate new one. It's simple and the `git gui` even has a menu for it.

Obviously you have to upload the public part of the new key to the server as an authorized key. That's usually simple as well.

That said the key is just a file (usually `.ssh/id_rsa`; the name depends on selected type) and can be copied.

Comment: I am new into this. So my understanding is , "The public key(.pub) is just a file with my email id" and I can create another one with the same email id. So the verification happens with the email id or the encrypted key? Because in both cases the encrypted key will be different. Let me know that I am missing anything or not.

Comment: @Cloud: Each private key comes with it's corresponding public key and the public key is used to verify the connection. The email is just a comment that is not used by ssh for anything at all. It does not even have to be there.